# Student Class. How to print Grade based off input of units?

Tags: java

```
public class Student {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private static int ID;
private String name;
private double units;
public String grade;

public Student(int ID, String name, double units) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.name = name;
    this.units = units;
}

public void setID(int ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public static int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setUnits(double units) {
    this.units = units;
}

public double getUnits() {
    return units;
}

public void setGrade(double units) {
    if (units < 30) {
        grade = "Freshman";
    } else if (units >= 31 && units <= 60) {
        grade = "Sophmore";
    } else if (units >= 61 && units < 90) {
        grade = "Junior";
    } else {
        grade = "Senior";
    }
}

public String getGrade(String grade) {
    return grade;
}

}
```

STUDENTTEST

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentTest {


public static void main(String[] args){
Student student = new Student(0, " ", 0);

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

int ID;
String name;
double unitsTaken;
String grade = "";

System.out.println("Student information:");
System.out.print("Student ID: ");
ID = scan.nextInt();
student.setID(ID);

scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("Student Name: ");
name = scan.nextLine();
student.setName(name);


System.out.print("Total Number of Units Completed: ");
unitsTaken = scan.nextDouble();
student.setUnits(unitsTaken);


    student.getGrade(grade);

    System.out.println("\nUpdated Student information");
    System.out.println("Student ID: " + ID);
    System.out.println("Student Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Total Number of Units Completed: " + unitsTaken);
    System.out.println("Class standing: " + grade);
}


}
```

Output:

```
Student information:
Student ID: 123123
Student Name: john
Total Number of Units Completed: 34

Updated Student information
Student ID: 123123
Student Name: john
Total Number of Units Completed: 34.0
Class standing:
```

The class standing won't print. I want it to print based off the amount of units entered. How come my method isn't working?

Comment: Get rid of `setGrade(...)` and instead make `getGrade()` use the formula currently in `setGrade` to figure out which String to return. In other words make grade a calculated or "derived" property

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels beat me to it. But... more specifically: you never actually call `setGrade()` anywhere. You just call `setUnits()` followed by `getGrade()`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how do I make it return the string? It says cannot convert double to string

Comment: As I stated above, move the if blocks found within `setGrade(...)` into `getGrade()` and have String returns within those blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question in a nutshell is, "how can two properties be dependent on one field?" The field in question is units, and it should have one and only one setter or "mutator" method. There should be two getter or accessor methods for the two properties, getUnit and getGrade. e.g.,

```
public class Student {
    private int units;

    public int getUnits() {
        return units;
    }

    public void setUnits(int units) {
        this.units = units;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        if (units < 30) {
            return "Freshman";
        } else if (units < 60) {
            return "Sophmore";
        } else if (units < 90) {
            return "Junior";
        } else {
            return "Senior";
        }
    }

    // Do not have a setGrade method!
}
```

This would make grade a calculated or "derived" property, one that is derived from the value of the unit field.

Note, this is in error:

```
student.getGrade(grade);
```

it should not use parameters:

```
student.getGrade();  // better
```

Another option is to create a *static* "utility" method for the calculation:

```
public static String getGrade(int units) {
    if (units < 30) {
        return "Freshman";
    } else if (units < 60) {
        return "Sophmore";
    } else if (units < 90) {
        return "Junior";
    } else {
        return "Senior";
    }
}
```

In this case, you would pass in the units int value and call the method in a static way:

```
System.out.println("Student grade: " + Student.getGrade(student.getUnits());
```

Comment: I get that, but my issue is when I call getGrade() in Student Test

Comment: @Tiblack9: but if you fix it with this, then `getGrade()` will work

Comment: @Tiblack9:  You're calling `getGrade()` wrong. Don't have it take a parameter.

Comment: Thank you (sorry I'm new to coding)!. I put System.out.println(grade); only not the method.

Comment: If i make a UML diagram for both these classes, would StudentTest have methods in the diagram? Or no because the method is not declared in that class?

Comment: @Tiblack9: that's a separate question unrelated to your main question, which I believe has been answered. If you need help for a new problem, then you may need to ask a new question.